# Cannot resolve symbol in libprotobuf in openwrt

Tags: openwrt, protocol-buffers, linker-errors, symbol-not-found

I have cross compiled a client server program to be run on openwrt plattform
I have used protoc version 2.6.1 to generate the .pb.h and .pb.cc files.

I have installed he protobuf package for cross compilation using the [this](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/obtain.firmware.sdk)
I have linked the compiled protobuf libraries to the source while compiling.

But when I try to run the executable on the openwrt VM (chaos calmer) it gives me the following error.

> symbol '_ZN6google8protobuf8internal13empty_string_B5cxx11E': can't
>   resolve the symbol in lib './opwenwrt-client'

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixxHp.png)

I can guess the that there is mismatch between  linking library.
But I dont understand that everywhere I am using protobuf version 2.1.6.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's probably caused by using a different compiler / C++ ABI to compile your application vs. libprotobuf.so. See this previous question for more:

[Undefined reference to google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_[abi:cxx11]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124264/undefined-reference-to-googleprotobufinternalempty-string-abicxx11)