# undefined reference to 'ClassName::memberField[abi:cxx11]'

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am trying to compile a code from a tutorial but I get an `ABI::CXX11 undefined reference error`. Here is the problematic code:

**Code-Listing-1 Node.hpp:**

```
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP

#include "Node.hpp"
#include <list>
using std::__cxx11::list;//I am forced to use std-c++11 because of wxWidgets 3.0.2
#include <cstdlib>

class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(const Node& orig);
    virtual ~Node();

    void setParent(Node * parent);
    Node * getParent();

    list<Node *> &getChildren();
    static list<Node *> &getNodes();

private:
    static list<Node *> nodes;
protected:
    list<Node *> children;
    Node * parent;

};

#endif /* NODE_HPP */
```

**Code-Listing-2 Node.cpp:**

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Node.hpp"

list<Node *> nodes;

Node::Node() {
    parent = NULL;

    nodes.push_back(this);//line 23
}

Node::Node(const Node& orig) {
}

Node::~Node() {
    nodes.remove(this);//line 30
}

void Node::setParent(Node * p){
    if( p == NULL && parent != NULL ) {
        parent->children.remove(this);
        parent = NULL;
    } else if( p->getParent() != this ) {
        parent = p;

        parent->children.push_back(this);
    }
}

Node * Node::getParent(){
    return parent;//line 53
}

list<Node *> &Node::getChildren(){
    return children;
}

list<Node *> &Node::getNodes(){
    return nodes;
}
```

And here are the errors I am getting:

```
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Node.o: In function `ZN4NodeC2Ev':
E:\Projects\CPP\wxWidgets/Node.cpp:23: undefined reference to `Node::nodes[abi:cxx11]'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Node.o: In function `ZN4NodeD2Ev':
E:\Projects\CPP\wxWidgets/Node.cpp:30: undefined reference to `Node::nodes[abi:cxx11]'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Node.o: In function `ZN4Node8getNodesB5cxx11Ev':
E:\Projects\CPP\wxWidgets/Node.cpp:53: undefined reference to `Node::nodes[abi:cxx11]'
```

From what I've seen/read, it has something to do with [the difference between std::list and std::list 2011.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/manual/using_dual_abi.html).

From what I've read [on an other stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124264/undefined-reference-to-googleprotobufinternalempty-string-abicxx11), using `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` should solve the issue, but it didn't change anything at all (I tried adding it to the C++ Compiler additional options and in the linker additional options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Code-Listing-2 Node.cpp:

```
#include "Node.hpp"

list<Node *> nodes;

Node::Node() {
   // ...
```

Should be:

```
#include "Node.hpp"

list<Node *> Node::nodes;

Node::Node() {
   // ...
```

Without `Node::`, you are declaring a global variable `nodes` unrelated to the static member `Node::nodes`, thus the undefined reference since a static member variable needs a proper definition.