# Undefined c++11 symbol while trying to create a Node.js binding to cld3

Tags: c++, node.js, linker, protocol-buffers, node.js-addon

I'm trying to compile a Node.js bindings for the Google's cld3 library. The entire code is available here: https://github.com/Aschen/node-cld3

A Node.js bindings is a dynamically linked library:

```
file build/Release/cld3.node
build/Release/cld3.node: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4df93d7ba762a9df6befaa072e54febf8d116bd8, with debug_info, not stripped
```

When I try to use the library through Node.js, I have an error when the program try to retrieve symbols from Protobuf library (used by cld3):

`Error: /build/build/Release/cld3.node: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf11MessageLite25InitializationErrorStringB5cxx11Ev`

If I build and run the program on my computer (Manjaro) then it works perfectly but when I try to compile and use it with [node:20](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/node/20/images/sha256-c6b8ae21142621595ae24ca50eeda1299a33bba46cfcc9f64f7ce62bc50cd56c?context=explore) (ubuntu based) or [debian:bookworm](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/debian/bookworm/images/sha256-d2739fe251cb9c90af305e6a980cb7edf16ae58eafc83e183f78dc0d51261abc?context=explore) then I have the error.

I have the feeling it has something to do with [c++11 Dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) (and the `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` macro maybe) because [I had to fix an old CMake configuration file](https://github.com/google/cld3/pull/85) in order to build the example from [github.com/google/cld3](https://github.com/google/cld3).

I tried to reproduce the build with the following Docker images (all available in the repository):

Docker manjarolinux/base:20230521 (working):

- g++ 12.2.1
- cmake 3.26.3
- libprotobuf 3.21.12
- Node.js 18.15.0

Docker node:20 (not working):

- g++ 10.2.1
- cmake 3.18.4
- libprotobuf 3.12.4
- Node.js 20.2.0

Docker debian:bookworm (not working):

- g++ 12.2.0
- cmake 3.25.1
- libprotobuf 3.21.12
- Node.js 18.13.0

It's like apart from Manjaro, the mangled symbols names from the protobuf library are not correct in the final `cld3.node` bindings but I don't understand why.

EDIT:

I found a difference when using `ldd` on the compiled `cld3.node` bindings, when it's compiled on the Debian or Ubuntu image, the `libprotobuf-lite.so` library is not listed

[image: missing linked library]

As suggested by @mmomtchev, I checked the ABI version for the Node.js binary (prebuilt), the libprotobuf-lite.so (prebuilt) and the cld3.node library (built) and they all seems to use the c++11 ABI (`objdump --demangle -tT /usr/lib/libprotobuf-lite.so | grep abi:` and so on)

Comment: Perhaps you could try to link with the protobuf library statically and see if that helps

Comment: To achieve this I first need to staticaly compile the protobuf library to something like libprotobuf.a, correct?

Comment: Yes, unless there is a precompiled static version available already.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure I can do that since a Node.js binding is a dynamic library (I edited the original post)

Comment: If you need -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 to fix anything, you just drop that thing and find another solution. Why would you use a piece of software that was not updated in 10 years?

Comment: Actually I fixed a compilation issue by removing this macro

Answer (score 0):

Your symbol demangles to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::InitializationErrorString[abi:cxx11]() const`

You can use this site to demangle: http://demangler.com/

Obviously, parts of your application are compiled with the C++11 `std::string` ABI, while others are not. Where is your Node.js coming from and where is `cld3` coming from? If are you using prebuilt binaries for everything, these problems are very difficult to avoid in some cases.

Refer to these answers:

[Undefined reference to google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_[abi:cxx11]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124264/undefined-reference-to-googleprotobufinternalempty-string-abicxx11)

[Linking problems due to symbols with abi::cxx11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159238/linking-problems-due-to-symbols-with-abicxx11)

Comment: Thansk for your answer, I appreciate! Is there any way for me to check with which version of the ABI a binary was compiled?

Comment: Yes, you can check the exported symbols with `objdump -tT` - you will have to demangle them

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. I also updated the original post because I found an interesting difference between the compiled libraries

Comment: I actually succeeded to compile bindings with Clang and then it works